# Conditional delay before emitting Single

Tags: android, rx-android

A RESTful API End-point returns a JSON Response.
The JSON Response consists of 20 different JSON-Array elements. Each element has a Image URL.

After receiving the first response, I intend to loop through the JSON-Array and fetch the images as well, using Retrofit Dynamic URLs.

```
class Content { var items List<Item>? = null }

class Item { var image: String? = null 
    var imageBytes: ByteArray? = null
}

interface RestApi { @GET fun getContent(): Single<Content>
@GET fun getImageBytes(@Url url: String): Single<ResponseBody>
}

restApi.getContent()
    .map { content: Content -> {
        content.items?.forEach { item ->
            restApi.getImageBytes(item.image)
                .subscribe(object : DisposableSingleObserver<ResponseBody>() {
                    onSuccess(body: ResponseBody) {
                        item.imageBytes = body.getBytes()
                    }
                    onError(e: Throwable) { // TODO Implementation }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I make the getContent() method delay before emitting until all invocations of the getImageBytes() also complete with either success or error?

Comment: add your url form getting json data

Comment: I do not wish to share the URL, it is not relevant to the issue. My only issue is delaying outer-subscription until all inner-subscriptions emit values in RxAndroid.

Answer (score 1):

With Single you should use flatten observable it will give a list of observables which the flat map will take up

```
 getListOfItems()
                .flattenAsObservable(new Function<Object, Iterable<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Iterable<?> apply(@NonNull Object o) throws Exception {
                        return toItems(o);
                    }
                })
                .flatMap(item -> doSomethingWithItem())
                .toList()
```

Comment: Any alternative other than having to explicitly cause a timer based delay will be appreciated. An alternative I could think of is a Boolean that will compare a countImageCallbacks incremented for every inner-observer invocation against countItems or the JSON-Array size, but I'll need that BooleanSupplier on the outer-observer to delay the subscription.

Comment: You can calculate the delay according to your logic and place it there that's totally upto you

Comment: Please provide sample source-code to fix and achieve desired functionality. A Single.repeatUntil(BooleanSupplier) could possibly be used to introduce a delay in subscription so outer-value is not emitted. I am missing how to introduce that repeatUntil operator.

Comment: Basically what you want is when all your all of  inner observables gets emitted after then only the outer(i.e getContent) should get completed if thats the case you should use flatmap not map